# set a condition inside render function and change state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set a condition inside the render function.
The code is as below:

```
class ListItems extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            active:false,   
        }
        this.toggleActive = this.toggleActive.bind(this);
    }
    toggleActive(){
        this.setState({
            active: !this.state.active
        })
    }   
    render(){   
        var demo = document.querySelector("#" + this.props.data);
        if(document.body.contains(demo)){
            this.toggleActive()
            return(
                <li className={this.state.active ? "active" : ""} onClick={this.toggleActive}>{this.props.data}</li>
            )
        }   
        else{
            return(
                <li className={this.state.active ? "active" : ""} onClick={this.toggleActive}>{this.props.data}</li>
            )
        }   
    }
}
```

it compiles successfully but returns this error while running:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
class ListItems extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            active:false,   
        }
        this.toggleActive = this.toggleActive.bind(this);
    }
    toggleActive(){
        this.setState({
            active: !this.state.active
        })
    }   
    componentDidMount(){
        var demo = document.querySelector("#" + this.props.data);
        if(document.body.contains(demo)){
            this.toggleActive()
            return(
                <li className={this.state.active ? "active" : ""} onClick={this.toggleActive}>{this.props.data}</li>
            )
        }   
    }
    render(){   
        return(
            <li className={this.state.active ? "active" : ""} onClick={this.toggleActive}>{this.props.data}</li>
        )
    }
}
```

let me know if that works?

Comment: you are very wellcome

Answer (score 1):

In your render you have  this.toggleActive()  which changes the state, causing a rerender, and which then again changes state, so this causes an intinite loop.

Just remove this line and try.

If you want to change state you can use componentDidMount  lifecycle:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.toggleActive();
}
```

Comment: if you want to update your state without click function then update your state inside componentDidMount, as this function will be auto called as your component mounted. and changing state in this function will cause re-render so you will be able to see the update.

Comment: @chauhanamit can you show me some code for example, please?

Comment: @HamedDehghan I added this info by editing answer, check please.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to following, you are basically calling the functions while rendering.

```
onClick={ e => {// your code} }
```

Comment: I want to call that function when the element is rendering. not clicking

Comment: @HamedDehghan this would lead to an infinite loop. Because render is called everytime the state changes. So if you change your state everytime render is called you will have an infiinite loop.

Comment: I have to change the state or something that solves this problem. thank you for your help.

Comment: can I set the condition outside of render?